# Is there any URL pattern I can use to open citymapper.com with a search predefined?

Tags: citymapper

I'm trying to create an [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) workflow that allows me to automatically open [citymapper.com](https://citymapper.com) with a pre-defined search result. I noted that if I type in two points of interest into the citymapper.com interface, it forms a URL like this:

https://citymapper.com/london/superrouter?start=51.515124,-0.141769&saddr=Oxford%20Circus&end=51.51621,-0.13087&eaddr=Tottenham%20Court%20Road

However - assuming that my workflow doesn't know the lat/lon of those places - if I simplify it like this:

https://citymapper.com/london/superrouter?saddr=Oxford%20Circus&eaddr=Tottenham%20Court%20Road

... it no longer works. Is there any way to open citymapper.com with a route already requested?

Comment: You can use Google Maps API to look up the latitude/longitude and then submit to citymapper, which is pretty much what citymapper is doing anyway: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/06/map-of-week-citymapper-android-app.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, to launch into Citymapper directions, you need to provide at least the lat/long of the destination. The details of our URL scheme are described [on this page](http://blog.citymapper.com/post/59578777734/launching-citymapper-directions-from-apps-and-the-web).

The web format is:

`https://citymapper.com/directions?startcoord=<lat>,<lon>&startname=<name>&startaddress=<address>&endcoord=<lat>,<lon>&endname=<name>&endaddress=<address>`

Citymapper needs `endcoord` and/or `startcoord` to be populated; at the moment it won't do any geocoding of names or addresses.

Comment: OK, thanks for the authoritative answer.